# ItemGroup repeatedly being added to project file

Tags: c#, visual-studio, csproj

I have two projects. Project A generates some cs files and writes them into a folder of project B. If the files exists, its overwrites them. These files are included in project B and are used to compile project B.

Whenever I run Project A, the ProjectB.csproj changes. It adds an ItemGroup stanza

```
<ItemGroup>
    <Compile Update="GeneratedFile.*.cs">
        <DependentUpon>GeneratedFile.cs</DependentUpon>
    </Compile>
</ItemGroup>
```

Why is this happening? How can I prevent this?

Comment: I think it is a feature in VS that identify connected files and show them hierarchy in Solution Explorer.

Comment: If this happens when you use the newer SDK-style project format, please open an issue at https://github.com/dotnet/project-system/